# Why does a function execute when put inside a variable (and how to stop it)

Tags: python

While writing a program in python i noticed that if one puts a function like `print("hello world")` inside a variable it will not be stored like expected, instead it will run. Also when i go and call the variable later in the program it will do nothing. can anyone tell me why this is and how to fix it?

Comment: It would help to see some code.

Comment: `print("hello world")` is not a function. It's a call to the function `print` with the argument `"hello world"`. Let's say you have the map `f(x)=2x`. Then `f(2)`  is not a function, it's `4`. `f` is the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mean something like:

```
variable = print("hello world")`
```

then calling the function is the expected result. This syntax means to call the `print` function and assign the returned value to the variable. It's analogous to:

```
variable = input("Enter a name")
```

You're surely not surprised that this calls the `input()` function and assigns the string that the user entered to the variable.

If you want to store a function, you can use a `lambda`:

```
variable = lambda: print("hello world")
```

Then you can later do:

```
variable()
```

and it will print the message